# Matrix equation with projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis

I need to solve the following equation for $P \in\mathbb{R}^{r\times d}$

$$P - G_1G_2(\lambda P^\top(PAP^\top)^{-1}P + A^{-1} ) = 0,$$

where the other quantities are known: $A\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$, $G_1 \in\mathbb{R}^{r\times d}$, $G_{2} \in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$, $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$.

I have already tried everything I know. If the equation had involved scalar quantities the solution would simply be
$$
p = g_1g_2(a^{-1}(1+\lambda)),
$$

but unfortunately in the matrix case I don't know how to proceed. Maybe there should be some way to decompose it using SVD or some trace trick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution for $P$ to
$$P - G_1G_2(\lambda P^\top(PAP^\top)^{-1}P + A^{-1} ) = 0$$
is
$$P=(1 +\lambda )G_1 G_2 A^{-1},$$
as one can check by substitution into
$$G_1G_2P^\top(PAP^\top)^{-1}P=G_1 G_2(G_1G_2A^{-1})^\top\bigl(G_1G_2(G_1G_2A^{-1})^\top\bigr)^{-1}G_1G_2A^{-1}=G_1G_2A^{-1}.$$